# Get elements from firebase rt database with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, axios

I'm building a quiz app for a project, I know that I should not be using the realtime database but for now I'm trying some operations with it. I did a login page in which I had to fetch the users I created in firebase with axios, and everything went fine. I was trying to do the same thing to fetch the questions I created in the database, but when I console log the questions the array seems to be empty. Can anyone help me to understand why? thank you

this is the code I used to fetch the users, that works fine:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const transformUsers = (userObj) => {
      const loadedUsers = [];

      for (const userKey in userObj) {
        loadedUsers.push({
          id: userKey,
          username: userObj[userKey].username,
          nome: userObj[userKey].nome,
          cognome: userObj[userKey].cognome,
          email: userObj[userKey].email,
          password: userObj[userKey].password,
        });
      }
      setUsers(loadedUsers);
    };
    getUsers(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseURL,
      },
      transformUsers
    );
  }, [getUsers]);
  console.log(users)
```

and this is the one I used for the questions, which returns an empty array:

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const transformQuestions = (questionObj) => {
      const loadedQuestions = [];

      for (const questionKey in questionObj) {
        loadedQuestions.push({
          id: questionKey,
          id_test: questionObj[questionKey].id_test,
          tipologia_domanda: questionObj[questionKey].tipologia_domanda,
          testo: questionObj[questionKey].testo,
          immagine: questionObj[questionKey].immagine,
          eliminata: questionObj[questionKey].eliminata,
        });
      }
      setQuestions(loadedQuestions);
    };
    getQuestions(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseURL,
      },
      transformQuestions
    );
  }, [getQuestions]);
```

for axios I created this use-axios Hook:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAxios = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const sendRequest = useCallback(async (params, applyData) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const response = await axios.request(params);
      applyData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return {
    isLoading,
    error,
    sendRequest,
  };
};

export default useAxios;
```

What am I missing?
[[example of the users and question database i created with firebase realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAf10.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN5WA.png)]